# How do I enable wireless on a Dell Vostro 3400

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, dell-vostro

I am using Dell Vostro 3400 PC. Previously I was running Ubuntu 11.10 version . Recenty I have upgraded it to 12.04 version. The sad part is wireless is disabled now and I am unable to connect internet.

How to enable wireless?

Comment: Please execute followings in terminal and post output of `lspci` and `rfkill list`

Comment: Have you connected (temporarily) by Ethernet, run updates and searched for additional drivers?  If so, then we need more details (as above).

Answer (score 2):

Actually I followed 2 step to enable wireless in my PC

- Step 1 : Removed the bcmwl-kernel-source package

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
  ```
- Step 2 : Installed the firmware-b43-installer package.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```

And then rebooted my PC .

Finally got my work done.  :)

Comment: Thanx @Jorge...