# Why is Ubuntu unable to connect to my wireless router? 

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, broadcom

I have just installed the latest version of Ubuntu and I want to connect to the Internet using my wireless router.

I tried using [`Ndiswrapper`](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)  but I received errors. I also tried using suggestions in this [`WiFiHowTo`](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo).

When I try installing from the additional drivers, I receive the error messages below.

```
Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

2012-05-15 19:14:29,861 DEBUG: Instantiated Handler subclass __builtin__.BroadcomWLHandler from name BroadcomWLHandler
2012-05-15 19:14:29,862 DEBUG: Broadcom STA wireless driver availability undetermined, adding to pool
2012-05-15 19:14:29,862 DEBUG: loading custom handler /usr/share/jockey/handlers/madwifi.py
2012-05-15 19:14:29,873 WARNING: modinfo for module ath_pci failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ath_pci
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci` so i can see exactly what Broadcom card you have?

Comment: The content of the log file `/var/log/jockey.log` might also be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem this weekend on a buddy's laptop. He has a Broadcom 4312.

I partially used [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/135558/26160) to another AskUbuntu question. The only difference is that once I removed:

`bcmwl-kernel-source`

I installed

`firmware-b43-installer`

and then rebooted.

The Network Manager showed the wireless card was installed, but displayed a message that the hardware switch was disabled.

Regardless of what I tried to enable (by clicking function and the wifi key) this would not change. I then decided to re-open the additional drivers and was able to activate the driver successfully. Once I restarted the machine, the wireless worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have Broadcom BCM4312 and using ndisgtk(ndiswrapper) worked perfectly. use windows driver for your wifi chipset (usually drivername.inf). reboot and most cases it worked. You can give it a try.

[image: ndiswrapper]